# Javascript/AJAX - Sending a reverse image search request to google

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

so i've been trying to do a reverse image search request through ajax, and it's giving me 302 errors. looking at the firebug console, i found out that the url in the response header sent back by google is linking me to the results, but i have no idea how to access that and send another ajax query to the new location. any help would be appreciated!

this is the response header: [image: Images]

This is my current code:

```
<form action="http://images.google.com/searchbyimage/upload" id="contactForm1" method="post"
    enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="image_url" id="image_url" />
    <input type="hidden" name="btnG" id="btnG" value="Search" />
    <input type="file" name="encoded_image" id="encoded_image" />
    <input type="hidden" name="image_content" id="image_content" />
    <input type="hidden" name="filename" id="filename" />
    <input type="hidden" name="hl" id="hl" value="en" />
    <input type="hidden" name="bih" id="bih" value="507" />
    <input type="hidden" name="biw" id="biw" value="1920" />
    <input type="button" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("form").bind("click", "input[type='button']", function () {
        var formData = new FormData($("form")[0]);
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "http://images.google.com/searchbyimage/upload",
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            data: formData,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (text) {
                console.log(text);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try with this:

```
 var formData = new FormData($(this).closest("form").serialize());
```